# Bookdown not rendering book Chapters

Tags: r, bookdown

I created a bookdown project in RStudio (OS: Windows 10, R 3.6.0, RStudio 1.3.959) and then knitted it. The resulting 'index.html' file looks great, but html files for chapters (e.g., blocks) are empty. Any idea what the problem might be?

Many thanks,
-Matan

Comment: You have to "build" your book and not knit the Rmd you are working on (in this case your index.Rmd). Check the RStudio top right corner (if you did not move the panel set up). There you should find a tab called "Build". Hit the build button there and the "whole" book will be built.
Alternatively you can call the function `render_book()` from your console. This will check for your `_bookdown.yml` and "build" the book with all pages.
If all fails, read up on the difference between building a book and previewing a chapter (knit): https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/editing.html

Comment: Thank you Ray, this makes sense!

Comment: why is that not an Answer :) ?